# Early Monero usage compared to Bitcoin

Tags: block-inverval

Has anyone done an analysis comparing Bitcoin usage its first two years compared to Monero usage in its first two years since launch?

I see some statistics here http://moneroblocks.info/stats but they only go back one year. Has the transactions per block data been adjusted according to the block time change from 1 to 2 minutes?

What factors today (spam attacks, different percentages of exchange related transactions, etc) might make such a comparison less useful or difficult?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "last month" stats from http://moneroblocks.info/stats shows 0.67 transactions per block on average, which equates to about 0.3 transactions a minute, since Monero has had two minute blocks for a few months now.

Based on the historical Bitcoin transaction rate posted by lethos3, Bitcoin averaged an equivalent rate of 3 transactions per (10 minute) block in early 2011, even late 2010.

The stats on moneroblocks.info show the average number of transactions to be relatively constant (last yeat shows 0.42 transactions per block, but a good amount of that year was spent with a minute between blocks).

The last spam attack on Monero was in 2014, so this is not a concern when comparing this page's stats with Bitcoin. One thing which might make some difference is that many people seem to have difficulty using simplewallet, and will thus either eschew Monero, or keep their coins on an exchange, despite the risks involved. The subset of those people who actually trade will therefore not have transactions to and between exchanges. Some people have stated they expect usage to pick up once the monero core GUI wallet is out.

Answer (score 3):

Comparing with [Bitcoin](https://blockchain.info/charts/n-transactions-per-block?timespan=all), since blocks in Monero are 5x "faster" (2 min X 10 min) we are roughly in mid-2012.

Comment: How do you get that ? The explorer shows 0.67 txes/block over last month, so about 3 txes per 10 minutes. Your link shows mid 2012 bitcoin with more than 100 txes per 10 minutes, if not 200. 3 looks more like early 2011. Am I reading the charts wrong ?

Comment: Yeah, I think 2012 is far too optomistic, it is probably more like 2010-2011. 2012 Bitcoin was already noticed by the Mainstream media (and being relentlessly bashed/misunderstood). From an exposure and usage standpoint it is still early days.